# Running a regex in GIT Bash, my file now has funny characters in it

Tags: c#, regex, encoding

I ran this regex in GIT BASH (I am on a windows machine, and I have GIT installed).

```
perl -pe 's/\[(?:xx_)?([^]]+)\]/\[\u$1\]/g'
```

The file now looks as if it is written in Chinese (it is a .sql schema file).

example:

```
嵛 嬀] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
```

Is there some encoding issue going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't that similar to [issue 358](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=358#c13)?

> Windows command line and GUI programs use different codepages by default.
>   For historical DOS compatibility, the command line ("OEM") [codepage is 437](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codepage_437), while the
>   GUI ("ANSI") [codepage is 1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252). See the [interesting reading here](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2005/03/08/389527.aspx).
>
> The console uses the OEM codepage (437 on my system) while the GUI uses the ANSI codepage (1252 on my system).
>   When launching a program from the console, `cmd.exe` usually does not modify the
>   arguments to that program, except if the program happens to be a `.bat` or `.cmd` file in
>   which case `cmd.exe` performs a codepage conversion on the arguments (see "[Codepage
>   Conversions](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/CaptureConsole.aspx)").
>   So `git.exe` already receives "Daniël" in 1252 encoding, which is
>   why it looks fine it looking at `.git/config` using Notepad.
>   When reading user.name, however, no codepage conversion takes place and "Daniël" in 1252 encoding is printed to the console, resulting in "Daniδl" on my system.
>   Obviously, the situation is different when using `MSYS / Git Bash`.
>
> So, to sum up, the solution when running Git from `cmd.exe` (via the `.cmd` wrappers)
>   seems to be to:
>
> 1) change the console font from a raster font to a True Type font,
>   2) change the console codepage via "`chcp`" to match the Windows codepage (whatever
>   that may be).

---

In short, a fix is coming: could you try this [beta Git installer](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=358#c20) and see if you still have the encoding issue?